# django error with use curl download CURLOPT_RESUME_FROM_LARGE

Tags: django, libcurl

i use django ,just for download file server.
and use curl to download file in client.
when i add CURLOPT_RESUME_FROM_LARGE for Resume broken transfer,Error come. 
i don't know it is server error or client error.
my client download code:

```
    FILE* ptmpfile = fopen((m_download_filepath_pre+tmpfilename).c_str(), "ab+");
    fseek(ptmpfile, 0L, SEEK_END);
    int currentsize = ftell(ptmpfile);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FILE, ptmpfile);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER ,0);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 0);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,60);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS ,0);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION ,my_progress_func);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSDATA ,sDownload);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_RESUME_FROM_LARGE, currentsize);
```

myserver error:

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 50232)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 582, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 323, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 139, in __init__
    super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 640, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 693, in finish
    self.wfile.flush()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

thanks～～

Fixed :) 
Client Error ,CURLOPT_RESUME_FROM_LARGE must get a curl_off_t parameter.

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_RESUME_FROM_LARGE, (curl_off_t)currentsize);
```

or use

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_RESUME_FROM, currentsize);
```

but who knows the different between CURLOPT_RESUME_FROM_LARGE and CURLOPT_RESUME_FROM?

Comment: So you're trying to start a file transfer in the middle of the file using Python to call a C library?

Comment: Client is C Code. i want it can  Resume broken transfer. so i add CURLOPT_RESUME_FROM_LARGE. but it not used.

Comment: From what you've posted so far it would be easy to conclude you've no idea what you're doing; but I'm sure that's not the case so perhaps make it plain what python code you're running and how it's being called.  It's easier than trying to guess that you've somehow got a curl client to open a socket with a uwsgi service and thence, well, ok I can't even guess what you've got happening after that.